showModal generates a TypeError not processed as a function
The following stimulus controller
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="dialog"
export default class extends Controller {
  
  connect() {
    this.open()
    // needed because ESC key does not trigger close event
    this.element.addEventListener("close", this.enableBodyScroll.bind(this))
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.element.removeEventListener("close", this.enableBodyScroll.bind(this))
  }

  // hide modal on successful form submission
  // data-action="turbo:submit-end->turbo-modal#submitEnd"
  submitEnd(e) {
    if (e.detail.success) {
      this.close()
    }
  }

  open() {
    this.element.showModal()
    document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden')
  }

  close() {
    this.element.close()
    // clean up modal content
    const frame = document.getElementById('modal')
    frame.removeAttribute("src")
    frame.innerHTML = ""
  }

  enableBodyScroll() {
    document.body.classList.remove('overflow-hidden')
  }

  clickOutside(event) {
    if (event.target === this.element) {
      this.close()
    }
  }
}

is, on page load generating the browser console error:
TypeError: this.element.showModal is not a function
What would be a proper way to ensure the function exists for the browser?

this.element seems to be a HTMLElement, probably the code should be this.showModal(). Elements don't have showModal and close methods. But ... this.close() in close method would most likely lead to infinite recursive calls, you've to check the naming of the methods.

Also, disconnect method doesn't work as it is. bind creates a new function object that doesn't refer to the same function which was passed to addEventListener in connect method. See ex. this answer to attach the listener, binding also this, so that the original reference is kept.
